# By selecting first combobox the remaining values should be displayed

Tags: javascript, extjs4

By selecting first extjs combo box, the remaining values should be displayed in the form.

I am creating an Address book application using Extjs.

By selecting first combobox the remaining values should be displayed in below form.

Below is the code:

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{name:'id', type: 'int'}, 
             {name: 'FirstName', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'EmailAddress', type: 'string'}]
});

user : [{"FirstName": "sssss", "EmailAddress": "bbb@gmail.com}, {"FirstName": "bbbb", "EmailAddress": "aaa@gmail.com"}]
```

By selecting FirstName from combobox EmailAddress should be displayed in the below textfield.

```
var cntry_panel = new Ext.Panel({
    header: false,
    id: 'org-main',
    layout: 'form',
    labelWidth: 200,
    border: false,
    bodyStyle: 'padding:15px',
    title: 'Select Country And State',
    labelAlign: "right",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combo',
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        id: 'Name',
        store: user, 
        displayField: 'FirstName',
        mode: 'remote',
        width: 260,
        forceSelection: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        emptyText: 'Select FirstName...',
     }, {
         xtype: 'combo',
         fieldLabel: 'Email Address',
         store: user, 
         mode: 'local',
         width: 150,
         forceSelection: true,
         triggerAction: 'all',
         selectOnFocus: true
    }]
});
```

Comment: A few things: First, you neither have data nor a textfield for "Homephone" in your code snippets (maybe you're talking about "EmailAddress"?) Second, I'd start with the docs for ComboBox. The select event passes a list of the selected records. You could easily pull the other data from the selected record and use it to populate other fields.

Comment: I am able to pull the data but I would like to display form.

Comment: Yes "Emailaddress", could you please provide example for pulling the data.

Answer (score 0):

First, your field for email address should probably be a `textfield`, unless you have a list of values that you are using for that field as a `combo`.

Next, give your Email field an `itemId` property, like `emailField`, for easy access.

Then, in your config for the First Name field, add a listener for the `select` event:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    fieldLabel: 'First Name',
    //...other properties...
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo, records) {
            combo.up('#org-main').down('#emailField').setValue(records[0].get('email'));
        }
    }
}
```

You should really check out the docs for events on `Ext.form.field.ComboBox`, this is a pretty common operation that will be important to understand if you will be using a lot of ExtJS.  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox

Comment: The correct parameters for the change event are: {this}, newValue, oldValue, eOpts

Comment: You are correct, I meant to type `select`, I have edited the post.